# Correctly outputting data from two looped arrays in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im working on this basic chat app in Vue.JS that acts like a chat bot concept where the user’s input triggers a written response. It works but I only know how to output the input and the response such as below. The problem with this is that the {{ data.message }} and {{ data.response }} are looped under eachother, giving no order to the convo.

The user's input get stored in the 'message' array. The message gets looped

```
<div class="userMessageC">
  <div class="userMessage" v-for="(data, index) in messages" :key='index'>
    {{ data.message }}
  </div>
</div>
```

while the bot's responses get stored in the responses array.

```
<div class="botMessageC" v-for="(data, index) in responses" :key='index'>
  <span class="botAvatar">
    <img src="@/assets/pimAvatar.png" width="50"/> 
  </span>           
  <div class="botMessage">
    {{ data.response }} 
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is that data.message is followed by data.response and then by data.message and then data.response and so on. How would I approach this?
This is how it looks (out of order)

[image].

[A jsfiddle to give you better idea](https://jsfiddle.net/zelm25/1Lg57mau/2/)

Comment: why you dont use 1 array `messages` instead of `messages` and `response`

Comment: On which element would I put the `v-for="(data, index) in messages" :key='index'` then?

Comment: store the time or index, concat the lists, and then sort them.  or do what Ifaruki said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you can use a computed property to update your messages and have the right order for both, questions and answers.

I don't understand well if is what you want to achieve, but is what I can understand.

Now, I suggest to identify every message with and Id (messageId) and attach the id to the response, then you can filter the response and put it in place once you get any response in any time.

I did some updates to your jsfiddle and you can see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ckbe1t57/28/) (I guess, I don't know very well how it works)

The template, if you want to have message then response, message then response, the better way is to have all in the same `v-for` statement:

```
<div class="messagesC"  v-for="(data, index) in rightOrder" :key='index'>
  <p class="userMessage">
    {{ data.message }}
  </p>
  <p class="botMessage">
    {{ data.response }}
  </p>            
</div>
```

Now in your methods you can add the Id

```
...
sendResponse() {
  const messageId = Math.random().toString(16).slice(2); // Generate uuid
  this.messages.push({
    message: this.message,
    messageId,
  }) // Push message with its id
  this.outputResponse(this.message, messageId);
},

outputResponse(input, messageId){ // receives message and messageId
  this.message = '';
  this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
    try {
        var output = input + "=" + eval(input);
    } catch (e) {
        var utterance = [
          ["hello"],
          ],intent = [
            ["hello back!"]
            ],fallback = ["this is a response to your input"];
        var text = (input.toLowerCase()).replace(/[^\w\s\d]/gi, "");    
        if (this.compare(utterance, intent, text)) {
            output = this.compare(utterance, intent, text);
        } else {
            output = fallback[Math.floor(Math.random() * fallback.length)];
        } 
    }
      this.responses.push({
       response: output,
       messageId
      }) // send back the response and the messageId
  }, 1000);
}
...
```

Now the computed property

```
computed: {
  // computed property that searches for an answer
  // taking into account the message order
  rightOrder() {
    return this.messages.map(message => {
      const response = {
      // Search a response with the messageId
      ...this.responses.find(
        response => response.messageId === message.messageId
      )}
      // return the message, messageId and its response
      return {
        message: message.message,
        ...response
      }
    })
  }
},
```

And finally the CSS

```
#window {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.userMessage {
  flex: flex-shrink;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.botMessage {
  flex: flex-shrink;
}
.messagesC {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.click {
  float: left;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5%;
}
```

You can send message without wait for the response, once the `responses` has a new response, it will be shown right after the message

Answer (score 4):

Because your "bot" is pretty much mocked, your problem is greatly simplified: it has the same response time and the results come back in the same order as they were sent. Which is not always true for a real server.

What you want to do is create an `utterance` or `pair` entity which holds both `message` and `response`, call the server from a method returning a promise and, when fulfilled, add the response to the utterance. In template all you need to do  is loop through utterances:

```
data: () => ({
  utterances: []
})
methods: {
  sendRequest(message) {
    const utterance = { message, response: '' };
    this.utterances.push(utterance);
    this.outputResponse(message).then(response => utterance.response = response);
  },
  outputResponse(message) {
    // do whatever you want to get response and return a resolved promise:
    return Promise.resolve(response);
  }
}
```

The template would look like this:

```
<div v-for="(u, key) in utterances" :key="key">
  <div v-text="u.message" />
  <div v-text="u.response" />
</div>
```

In a real life scenario, where the call to bot might actually be decoupled from your component, you'll likely want to give each utterance an [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) and map the response back to the utterance based on that unique identifier.
Also, recording the timestamp at which the message was input opens your door to storing and re-rendering them at a future time in the order they were sent.

---

The `outputResponse` method is a bit over-simplified above. Calling an actual server would look something like this:

```
outputResponse(message) {
  return axios.get('https://your.bot', params: { message })
    .then(response => response.data)
}
```

... assuming the bot responds with a simple string.

---

See it working.
To make it act more like a real life server, I made the "bot" response take a variable time, between 1 and 15 seconds:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    utterances: [],
    message: ''
  }),
  methods: {
    send(message) {
      const utterance = {
        message,
        response: ''
      };
      this.utterances.push(utterance);
      this.getResponse(message).then(response => utterance.response = response);
      this.message = '';
    },
    getResponse: message => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(`<pre> => </pre>${message} back...`);
      }, (Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1) * 1e3)
    })

  }
})
```

```css
pre {
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <input v-model="message" @keyup.enter="send(message)">
    <button @click="send(message)">Send</button> (or press enter)
  </div>
  <div v-for="(u, k) in utterances" :key="k" style="display: flex">
    <div v-text="u.message"></div>
    <div v-html="u.response"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is good, especially your explanation at the bottom, however you need to set property response ahead of time, or Vue's built-in object mutation hooks won't be able to pick up the change to response.  Or splice it in later, so a new reference can be detected by change detection.

Comment: @user120242, when I first read your comment, I thought you were right, but you're not. Because it's an entry in the `utterances` array, every entry is observed and so are any mutations to them. You can see the demo working without declaring the `response` before `.push()`. I do appreciate your input and, again, I thought you were right until I actually tested it.

Comment: are you sure?  I just tested it and it definitely doesn't work if you don't declare response in the object you push to the array.  The runnable snippet you have above declares response with the empty string, so it works, but your code block at the top doesn't declare response in the pushed object

Comment: Yes, you ***are*** right. I thought it worked because without it, the template gets updated if any change is made to it (input gets focused or changed). However, if I quickly input a few and don't touch it anymore (and the `response` is not declared), it doesn't get updated. They all show up as soon as I focus the input again. So `response` definitely needs to be declared before `.push()`. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Very much appreciate you going the extra mile for this!

Answer (score 1):

You could reference the index of the response like below. So it will show message on top and then response associated to that message below. You can use a ternary to do error handling as well in case there is a message but no response your code will not break

```js
<div class="userMessageC">
  <div class="userMessage" v-for="(data, index) in messages" :key='index'>
    <p>{{ data.message }}</p>
   <p> {{responses[index].response ? responses[index].response : ""}}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Couple of typos in the code; should be `responses[index]`

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Other than the typos, it seems fine

Comment: @Stephen Thomas I downvoted.  Many problems. He's not using the `.response` property.  Two syntax errors.  No line break causes it to render as one line. He changed the original DOM structure.  He didn't address the problems with the original code.  Ternary for error handling?  Basically the same fix as I made but 15 minutes later and incorrect and no demo.  This code was evidently not properly thought through nor tested.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably created a computed property that combined messages and responses and iterate over that

```
computed: {
  messagesAndResponses() {
    return this.messages.map((m, i) =>
      ({message: m.message, response: this.responses[i]})
    );
  }
```

then in the template

```
<div 
    v-for="(m,i) in messagesAndResponses"
    :key="i"
>
  <div class="userMessageC">
    <div class="userMessage">
      {{ m.message }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="botMessageC">
    <span class="botAvatar">
      <img src="@/assets/pimAvatar.png" width="50"/> 
    </span>           
    <div class="botMessage">
      {{ m.response }} 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```